# Creating a column from another columns text only

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a data frame in R that contains column with both letters and numbers.  The number of letters and numbers vary, so parsing would be incredibly difficult.  What I would like to do is simply create a column that contains only the letters from the column containing the letters and numbers.  A typical observation would look like ABS98 or GD798.

Thanks

Comment: Would simple text replacement do it - `gsub("[0-9]","",dat$col1)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use a regular expression via `gsub()`. Using something like your data:

```
df <- data.frame(Ind = rep(c("ABS98","GD798"), each = 5), Dat = rnorm(10))
```

One possible regular expression is:

```
with(df, gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", Ind))
```

where `"[[:digit:]]"` matches whatever passes for a digit in your locale and replaces those bits with an empty string `""`. This gives us:

```
> with(df, gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", Ind))
 [1] "ABS" "ABS" "ABS" "ABS" "ABS" "GD"  "GD"  "GD"  "GD"  "GD"
```

To add this as a column either overwrite `Ind`:

```
df2 <- transform(df, Ind = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", Ind))

> head(df2)
  Ind        Dat
1 ABS  0.3685773
2 ABS  0.1186962
3 ABS -0.1049685
4 ABS -0.2448743
5 ABS -0.1896105
6  GD  0.8206612
```

or add a new one

```
df3 <- transform(df, Ind2 = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", Ind))

> head(df3)
    Ind        Dat Ind2
1 ABS98  0.3685773  ABS
2 ABS98  0.1186962  ABS
3 ABS98 -0.1049685  ABS
4 ABS98 -0.2448743  ABS
5 ABS98 -0.1896105  ABS
6 GD798  0.8206612   GD
```

depending on which suits your use-case best.

Comment: How is this essentially different for @thelatemail comment and why do you need `*` there? In which cases `with(df, gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", Ind))` won't work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg It isn't but when I started writing this there were no responses (but I got distracted and it took a while to finish). The only way this improves on that comment is that I tried to explain the regexp *and* offer two options for replacing or adding a new column. The `*` isn't needed; I was trying out an example with a back reference as the replacement and there I seemed to need a `*` and didn't remove it when I pasted the simpler regexp.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, what's the concern? That Gavin hijacked Thela's answer? If Thela wanted to post an answer it would have been done. I personally prefer answers in the answer space and not in comments. That it's a duplicate? Find the dupe and others would surely appreciate it, though note that not all duplicates must necessarily be closed.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I didn't accuse Gavin in hijacking the answer, so please refrain from posting populist comments on my behalf. All I said is that I don't see the significant difference between this and Thelas comment and I thought it could have just been another comment of "or `gsub("[[:digit:]]","",dat$col1)`". But now that he explained it, it seems legit.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `?"regular expression"` suggests that `[foo-bar]` character classes, either for digits or other characters is not necessarily portable - so the `[:digit:]` class could be seen as a more defensive choice than `[0-9]` *in case* the simpler `[0-9]` fails on some system somewhere. When I see comments like those of @thelatemail's above, I presume they don't have time to flesh out an answer and if I have the time (and in this case I'm not  as familiar with regexp as I should be so it was a refresher for me too), then I will add an Answer, even if it duplicates the comment

Answer (score 3):

gsub works perfectly well.  Use that to strip out all of the numbers and place the results in col2 (or whatever your target field is).

```
df=data.frame(col1=c("ABS98", "GD798", "45j9s"))
df$col2=gsub("[0-9]","",df$col1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `stri_replace_charclass` function from `stringi` package:

```
stri_replace_all_charclass(c("AB89","DB12"),"\\p{N}","")
## [1] "AB" "DB"
```

First argument is the vector you want to modify, second is character class (in this case N - numbers) and the third is the replacement - an empty string.

```
x <- stri_rand_strings(1000,10,c("[A-Z]","[0-9]"))
x[1:6]
## [1] "OGYLERNWUV" "2397448180" "DPQWSDODVD" "4176825763" "GEFNQMIXMO" "7178890572" 
microbenchmark(stri_replace_all_charclass(x,"\\p{N}",""), gsub("[0-9]","",x,perl =  TRUE), gsub("[0-9]","",x))
Unit: microseconds
                                          expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 stri_replace_all_charclass(x, "\\\\p{N}", "")  385.002  398.2755  405.5475  415.9865  603.859   100
             gsub("[0-9]", "", x, perl = TRUE)  748.432  756.3290  763.3345  779.4150 1127.759   100
                          gsub("[0-9]", "", x) 1452.630 1467.0205 1482.3825 1503.4140 1755.422   100
```

Comment: Just curious - what's the advantage of this over `gsub`?

Comment: @bartektartanus: just curious, could you compare that also with `gsub(..., perl=TRUE)`?

Comment: Also, `\p{N}` is much broader than `[0-9]`. `stri_replace_all_charclass` can also be fed with `[0-9]`

Comment: It's faster, but still slower than `stringi` :)